# How can I align my text and input box on the same row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried using bootstrap for aligning my text and input box on the same row but it's not working:

```
<tr id="price_box">
    <div class="row">
        <th>Price:</th>
        <td>
            Rs&nbsp;
            <input id="price" name="price" type="text" value="">
            <span class="pricebox_end">.00</span>
    </div>
    <br>(Optional - do not include period, comma or cents)
    <div id="err_price" style="display: none">
        <span class="warning nohistory"></span>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

The above is just a fragment, but I could make a fiddle if it helps. Maybe you know what I should do to make the texts and the input box display on the same row?

### Update

The following rendered them on the same row.

```
 <tr id="price_box">

            <th>Price:</th>
            <td>

<div style="float:left">
                Rs
</div>
                &nbsp;<input id="price" name="price" type="text" value=""><span class="pricebox_end">.00</span>




                    <br>(Optional - do not include period, comma or cents)
```

With the CSS.

```
#price {
    float:left;
}
.pricebox_end {
    float:left;
}
```

I had to keep the table because of complex side effects if I removed the table.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't know if table rows and bootstrap grid rows play nicely together

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have malformed HTML with tables and Bootstrap thrown in. I would just use the grid system:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
         Price:
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="price" name="price" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Rs
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="pricebox_end">.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The grid system is a nice replacement for HTML tables. Bootstrap lets you write less HTML and gives you responsiveness out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The div `<div class="row">` HTML element in your code is not a valid direct child element for `<tr>` and adds unexpected behaviour.

Further, the `<input id="price" .. >` element wasn't closed, causing the issue of the elements not being rendered on the same row. You do not need to float your elements.

You can close an `input` element by doing `<input id=price .. />` or `<input id=price ../></input>`

I've cleaned up your code below.

```
<tr id="price_box">
    <th>Price:</th>
    <td>
Rs <input id="price" name="price" type="text" value="" /><span class="pricebox_end">.00</span>
        <br />
        (Optional - do not include period, comma or cents)
    </td>
</tr>
```